# Pause receiving rabbitmq messages

Tags: javascript, rabbitmq

I'm trying to create a simple work queue-like application based on rabbitmq: one server creating tasks, and several workers processing these tasks. [The example from rabbitmq docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-javascript.html) suits me rather well: I create a single queue, one producer that pushes tasks to the queue and several workers that consumes the tasks.

This is my code, based on the example mentioned, and adapted for promise-style code:

new_task.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var amqp = require('amqplib');

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

async function run() {
  const connection = await amqp.connect('amqp://localhost')
  const channel = await connection.createChannel()
  var queue = 'task_queue';
  var msg = process.argv.slice(2).join(' ') || "Hello World!";

  channel.assertQueue(queue);
  channel.sendToQueue(queue, Buffer.from(msg));
  console.log(" [x] Sent '%s'", msg);
  await sleep(500)
  connection.close();
  process.exit(0)
}

run()
```

worker.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var amqp = require('amqplib');

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

async function run() {
  const connection = await amqp.connect('amqp://localhost')
  const channel = await connection.createChannel()
  var queue = 'task_queue';

  channel.assertQueue(queue);
  channel.prefetch(1);
  console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", queue);
  channel.consume(queue, async function (msg) {
    var secs = msg.content.toString().split('.').length - 1;
    console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
    await sleep(secs * 1000)
    console.log(" [x] Done");
    channel.ack(msg);
  }, {
    noAck: false
  });
}

run()
```

Everything works well, but my problem is that from time to time the workers need to pause receiving messages for some unrelated work (recalibration). While a worker recalibrates, I want all the messages to be processed by other workers, and no messages stuck waiting for the recalibration.

The simple approach:

worker.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var amqp = require('amqplib');

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

var need_calibrate = false

async function recalibrate() {
  console.log("Recalibration...")
  await sleep(10000)
  console.log("Done recalibration...")
  need_calibrate = false  
}

async function run() {
  const connection = await amqp.connect('amqp://localhost')
  const channel = await connection.createChannel()
  var queue = 'task_queue';

  channel.assertQueue(queue);
  channel.prefetch(1);
  console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", queue);
  channel.consume(queue, async function (msg) {
    if (need_calibrate) {
      await recalibrate()
    }
    var secs = msg.content.toString().split('.').length - 1;
    console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
    await sleep(secs * 1000)
    console.log(" [x] Done");
    channel.ack(msg);
    if (msg.content.toString().includes("b")) {
      need_calibrate = true
    }
  }, {
    noAck: false
  });
}

run()
```

obviously does not work as expected, because I start recalibration only after receiving a message, and thus this message has to wait for recalibration, while I would like to see it processed on another worker.

I was considering closing the connection while recalibrating, but there seem to be no good moment to do this, because closing a connection before an `ack` for the previous message will lose the `ack`, and right after I ack a message, I immediately recieve the next one.

I was also considering rejecting or nacking the message before starting recalibration, but this will only lead to my worker immediately receiving a next message...

I also know that there is `Channel#get` that allows to get exactly one message, but it would not wait for a new message, so I'll have to call it many times in a loop, which definitely is not a good decision.

What I would like to have is `async Channel#get` that will wait until exactly one message is available, so that I could write something along the lines

```
  console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", queue);
  while (true) {
    if (need_calibrate) {
      await recalibrate()
    }
    const msg = await channel.get()
    var secs = msg.content.toString().split('.').length - 1;
    console.log(" [x] Received %s", msg.content.toString());
    await sleep(secs * 1000)
    console.log(" [x] Done");
    channel.ack(msg);
    if (msg.content.toString().includes("b")) {
      need_calibrate = true
    }
 }
```

...but there is no such function.

So, is there any good way to indicate to pause receiving messages, without losing any message?

Comment: have you considered injecting "recalibration" messages in the queue, potentially referencing a worker, and if a process receives such message, nack and requeue so it's picked up by another process?

Comment: @Olivier that sounds as a promising idea, I'll consider it, thanks!